# How to run Grails app WAR file on Apache web server?

Tags: java, apache, grails, deployment, war

I want to know if it is possible to run a Grails app (basically a Java WAR file) on Apache web server. Currently I am using Tomcat but I need some Apache specific configurations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291818/how-to-deploy-war-file-in-apache2-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run a Grails application (WAR) on an Apache HTTP webserver. A Java WAR requires a JEE application container such as Tomcat or Jetty to run.

Depending on your needs you could put an Apache HTTP webserver in front of a Tomcat server which runs your Grails application. This way you can use the features of the Apache HTTP webserver as well as what is offered by Tomcat. However, this is beyond the scope of the question you asked.

Comment: In fact, I think it is a good suggestion. But how can I put an Apache web server in front of a Tomcat server?

Comment: @ManuelCalles that's an entirely different question and beyond the scope of SO. Google the topic of "tomcat apache frontend" and you will find lots of information.